# how to scan a character and integer together in c

Tags: c, scanf

I am writing code for scanning character and integer together in the format like
R 2

but the following code gives unexpected result and i am not able to scan a character and integer togather

```
int main()
{
long int m,i;
scanf("%ld",&m);
char que[m];
long int d[m];
for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
    scanf("%c ",&que[i]);
    scanf("%ld",&d[i]);
}
for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
    printf("%c  %ld",que[i],d[i]);
}
```

Comment: Edit your code it gives error as of now

Comment: Next time onwards, be a little more specific. Instead of saying "_the following code gives unexpected result_", explain whats "unexpected" and what happens clearly.

Comment: the presentation of the posted code has problems with: 1)  missing/inconsistent indenting 2) #include statements missing (are we expected to guess what header files to use?) 3)trailing lines of the function. 4) error checking of the scanf() calls 5) multiple variable declarations in one statement,  6) no prompts when user input wanted 7) meaningless variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a space before the `%c` in `scanf()` to excape the left out newline `\n` character.

After the change, the code works fine, check out below..

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long int m,i;
    scanf("%ld",&m);
    char que[m];
    long int d[m];
    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
        scanf(" %c",&que[i]);
        scanf("%ld",&d[i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
        printf("%c  %ld\n",que[i],d[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you create array like this:

```
char que[m];
```

You will create a static array of char, which is needed to be given an exact value (and also can't be changed/constant) of how big you want your array to be, so you can't put 'm' there. The same goes to:

```
long int d[m];
```

Second, if you use C, you really can't declare the data type of variable after you use a function in your program (in your case, you declare the array of char and array of long int after you put `scanf()`).

Third, if you press 'Enter' after give the input, the input will be read by line 1 (`i = 0`), and will put `\n` in line 2 (`i = 1`), because the `\n` is still in the buffer (in `scanf()` case, `stdin`). It's one of an error that will happen if you use `scanf()`. There is at least 2 solutions to this:

1.Put `fflush(stdin)` after every `scanf()` (not recommended since `fflush()` is supposed to be used with output stream, not input stream)

2.Create a function like this:

```
void clear(void) {
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    return;
}
```

and use `clear()` after every `scanf()`.